# Stream a NOT NULL selection of a table?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to select the primary key for all rows in a table based on if another column is NULL.
The following code **does not** do what I want, but this is what it would look like as a pure **select()**, but the table is so large that it nearly fills up memory before returning any results.

```
s = tweets.select().where(tweets.c.coordinates != None)

result = engine.execute(s)

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Because the table is so large, I found a streaming solution that works for the **session.query()** object:

```
def page_query(q):
r = True
offset = 0
while r:
    r = False
    for elem in q.limit(1000).offset(offset):
       r = True
       yield elem
    offset += 1000
```

so I'm trying to structure the above **select()** as a **query()**, but when I do, it returns every row in the table, including ones with `coordinates = 'null'`

```
q= session.query(Tweet).filter(Tweet.coordinates.is_not(None))
for i in page_query(q):
    print(f' {i}')
```

If I instead do

```
q= session.query(Tweet).filter(Tweet.coordinates.is_not('null'))
for i in page_query(q):
    print(f' {i}')
```

I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "'null'"
LINE 3: WHERE milan_tweets.coordinates IS NOT 'null' 
                                              ^
```

(using `!=` appears to give the same results as the built in `.is_not()`)

So how can I make this selection?

EDIT: Code block at the top does NOT do what I expected originally, my mistake.
Rows are added to the database as python `None`s, and looking in dbeaver shows the values as `"null"`

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly diagnosed the problem.
Query returns e.g. a million rows,
and the psycopg2 driver drags *all*
of those result rows over the network,
buffering them locally, before returning
even a single row up to your app.

Why? Because the public API includes a
detail where your app *could* ask
"how many rows were in that result?",
and the driver must retrieve all in order
to learn that bit of trivia.

If you promise not to ask the "how many?"
question, you can **stream** results with this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(uri).execution_options(stream_results=True)
```

Then rows will be up-delivered to your app
nearly
as soon as they become available,
rather than being buffered
a long time.
This yields a significantly smaller
memory footprint for your python process,
as the DB driver layer does not need
to `malloc()` storage sufficient to
store all million result rows.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#streaming-with-a-fixed-buffer-via-yield-per
cf [test_core_fetchmany_w_streaming](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/performance/large_resultsets.html)

Comment: Thank you! This makes the select version stream nice and speedily, but it appears I asked too soon; the code block that I thought did work, the select() version, also just returns every row. My mistake!